# How to make a proper line break in a C++ program

Tags: c++

What is wrong with my code? I try to get a line break using both `\n` and `endl` but it shows an error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int MinutesPerHour = 60;
    const float PI = 3.14;
    cout << MinutesPerHour;endl;
    cout << PI;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `cout << MinutesPerHour << endl;`?

Comment: To use `\n`, you need to put it in a string, eg: `cout << MinutesPerHour << "\n";`

Answer (score 1):

You should place the `endl` after the output stream operator `<<`.

Like this:

```
 cout << MinutesPerHour << endl;
```

Comment: Since it's a new paragraph, two newlines would be better.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.